# Colour specific area on a map using R (map packages)

Tags: r, dictionary, package

I would like to create a simple map with the package maps in R. The code for the map is:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(maptools)  
library(scales)  
map("worldHires", xlim=c(-20,70),ylim=c(30,90), col="gray90", fill=TRUE)
```

On top of that, I would like to color the region bounded by `xlim=c(-20,70)`, `ylim=c(30,52)` as `col="blue"`

Any idea about how to do that? Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: `rect(-20,30,70,52, col="blue")`? Is that what you're talking about? I'm guessing "no" but I can't think of another way to interpret your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without problems using `rect()`:

```
rect(-20, 30, 70, 52, col=alpha("blue", 0.5))
```

Which gives you the map below.
[image]

If you want to add shapes other than a rectangle, you could try `polygon()` or similar functions from the base graphics.